# Rails server is running but cannot connect to it in web browser in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, server, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to set-up Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 14.04 and I am using an Azure virtual machine. Everything is done. I installed Ruby, Rails and Bundler.

When I start the server it runs perfectly but I cannot see the "WELCOME ABOARD" or any start page and I cannot connect it through my browser.

When I run `rails s`  Webrick starts successfully and it says:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in development on     http://localhost:3000
=> Run rails server -h for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-01-29 20:47:14] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-01-29 20:47:14] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-01-29 20:47:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1655 port=3000
```

I also tried binding it with my public address. I  tried everything I know.

Comment: i use vagrant, i think you have to bind ip. try 'rails s -b 0.0.0.0'

Comment: Are you attempting to browse to `localhost:3000` from within your virtual machine or the host operating system? An important distinction to make.

Comment: I tried running the server on local host it runs fine. I was supposed to get the 'WELCOME ABOARD' page on the public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot connect to localhost from aside.
Try start rails with following arguments:

```
 rails s -b {PUBLIC IP} -p 3000
```

where `{PUBLIC IP}` is IP address of your server